# post django form data via iframe

Tags: django, iframe, django-views, django-forms

I have a django form that I want to display on another website via iframe. The form displays ok but whenever I try to submit the form that is displayed in the iframe, I get a "server refused to connect" error message.

Is it possible to make a django form work with iframe or is there a better way to do it?

The views code for the form:

```
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt


@xframe_options_exempt
def booking_create_view(request):
    form=BookingForm
    submitted = False
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = BookingForm
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True

    return render(request, "booking_form.html",{'form':form, 'submitted': submitted})
```

HTML for the form:

```
<form class="" action="" method= POST>
  <div class="form-group">


  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="Submit"  value="Submit" class = "btn btn-secondary">
</form>
{% endif %}
```

The iframe:

```
    <h1>The iframe element</h1>

<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/" title="test">
</iframe>
```

Note: I have also tried using a live server (pythonanywhere) that had the same result

Comment: Try using the browser's developer tools to see what network connections are made when you submit the form -- it sounds like it might be trying to submit to the wrong URL for some reason.  Once you've found out what URL it's posting to, if the solution isn't obvious, you can update your question with the URL it is using.

Comment: Well im sure its going to the right url. The browser shows a 403 forbidden error and the terminal shows csrf cookie not set

Comment: You should probably update the question, then -- you said 'I get a "server refused to connect" error message', which something different.  If you're getting a 403, then perhaps the CSRF token template tag you're using is wrong in some way?

Comment: I solved the issue. You were right about the CSRF token. I just added @csrf_exempt to the view and i was able to submit the form.